# Man broke, possibly on installing git, how do I fix?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, git, manpages

I am running Mac snow leopard 10.6.3 and I used a mac installer program for git that was designed originally for leopard. I think since then my man pages have been broken and attempting to look up any command makes my computer stall for a bit before returning 'no manpage found.' Where do I begin fixing this? Thanks.

Here's the debug output for man man:

```
$ man -d man
Reading config file /private/etc/man.conf
Looked whether there exists a message catalog man, but there is none
(and for English messages none is needed)

found man directory /usr/share/man
found man directory /usr/local/share/man
found man directory /usr/X11/man
found manpath map /bin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /sbin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/bin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/sbin --> /usr/share/man
found manpath map /usr/local/bin --> /usr/local/share/man
found manpath map /usr/local/sbin --> /usr/local/share/man
found manpath map /usr/X11/bin --> /usr/X11/man
found manpath map /usr/bin/X11 --> /usr/X11/man
found manpath map /usr/bin/mh --> /usr/share/man

using /usr/bin/less -is as pager

using /usr/bin/less -is as browser

using /bin/cat to dump HTML pages as text
path directory /usr/bin is in the config file
adding /usr/share/man to manpath

path directory /bin is in the config file

path directory /usr/sbin is in the config file

path directory /sbin is in the config file

path directory /usr/local/bin is in the config file
adding /usr/local/share/man to manpath

path directory /usr/local/git/bin is not in the config file
but there is a man directory nearby
adding /usr/local/git/share/man to manpath

path directory /usr/X11/bin is in the config file
adding /usr/X11/man to manpath

adding mandatory man directories

No manual entry for man
```

Comment: All these checks seem to work out. Nothing that I can see is obviously wrong. Clearly something is happening with the git, but I don't know enough to know what that might do to my manpath if anything.

Comment: Here is $ man --path:

/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/git/share/man:/usr/X11/man

Comment: $MANPATH is empty

Comment: What's in `/usr/share/man`?

Comment: $ ls /usr/share/man
fr   man3   pl
fr.ISO8859-1  man4   pl.ISO8859-2
fr.UTF-8  man5   pl.UTF-8
it   man6   ru.KOI8-R
it.ISO8859-1  man7   ru.UTF-8
it.UTF-8  man8   whatis
man1   man9   whatis (from old Mac)
man2   mann

Comment: Okay, then what's in `/usr/share/man/man1`?

Comment: a ton of zipped files and some files ending with .1 as an extension. Here are a few:


ImageUnitAnalyzer.1  esac.1.gz
LaunchCFMApp.1   escputil.1.gz
[.1.gz    etags.1.gz

Comment: Is man.1 or man.1.gz in there?

Comment: doesnt look like it:


$ ls /usr/share/man/man1/ | grep man

command.1.gz
dbmmanage.1.gz
hdxml2manxml.1

Comment: Actually, it looks like it doesn't contain anything that is alphabetically after "l". The last entry is lprm.1.gz

Comment: I can man "egrep" but not "ls." Wtf

Comment: `Man broke` is the best start of a title ever

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that what you've installed has added some extra directories to your `MANPATH` and likely nuked some standard directories from `MANPATH`.

First run `man --path` to determine which directories `man` will search for man pages. Here's what I see:

```
$ man --path
/opt/local/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/local/mysql/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/X11/man
```

If you don't see `/usr/share/man` in this output, you won't get standard man pages.

The delay you're seeing could also be related to `man` rebuilding its index of pages and/or doing some preformatting for the stuff you've installed.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like Doug's answer as the quick, simple, and likely thing to try first. I wouldn't be surprised if that git installer set your MANPATH environment variable, which is usually unset. If they did it by "MANPATH=$MANPATH:/path/to/git/man/pages", it would only contain the path to the git man pages, and since it overrides /etc/man.conf, that could explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, `man man`, but I guess that wouldn't help you! :-)

First, do `which man` to make sure you're still running the Mac OS X system default `/usr/bin/man`. Check to make sure it's not corrupted. FWIW, on my 10.6.3 system, here's its md5:

```
$ md5 `which man`
MD5 (/usr/bin/man) = 20c983ccab20dbea7aa76608b27aa148
```

Next, look at `/etc/man.conf` to see how your `MANPATH` is configured (note: this won't necessarily show up in your `$MANPATH` environment variable).

In case you want to check if your `man.conf` got corrupted, here's some summary info on mine. I'm on 10.6.3 also, and I don't think I've ever changed my `man.conf`:

```
$ md5 /etc/man.conf  
MD5 (/etc/man.conf) = 56592a53f75e08418362d2cfcf675e52  
$ wc -l /etc/man.conf  
     140 /etc/man.conf
```

If your `man.conf` looks sane, start looking at the MANPATH paths it specifies to see if those directories exist and are populated appropriately.  `/usr/share/man` is a big one.

I suppose you could check your man cat dir (cached versions of prerendered man pages) as well, but on my 10.6.3 system, there doesn't appear to be a cat dir for man pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for forever on OS X 10.6.x (where x has been at least 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, & 8).

Today, I finally got frustrated with it and have been following whatever online threads I could find.  Thanks primarily to the troubleshooting suggestions on this page, I solved the problem.  It turns out that the solution to the problem on my computer was hinted at in the comments by Spiff and user37929.  My /usr/share/man folder was missing LOTS of key files including man.1.gz (I didn't have precisely user37929's problem because I did have files in the man1 folder that began with letters after "L").  Once I copied several of the missing files from a friend's computer, the man pages returned and I don't get the error any more (for the ones I copied).

So, in my case it looks like I need a wholesale restoration of /usr/share/man.  That'll be a project for a future day!

Oh, and I installed git forever ago too, but I think I had this problem before that.